# Get the selected seats array into the state variable React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the selected checkbox name into an array. Then, I want to use it later for some calculations. but when I try to get the values it's giving the wrong values. I want to allow users to select the ticket count by using the +/- buttons. following is my code

**Code**

Getting the selected seat from the checkboxes

```
const [seatCount, setSeatCount] =React.useState("");
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

var seatsSelected = []    
const handleChecked = async (e) => {
  let isChecked = e.target.checked;
  if(isChecked){
    await seatsSelected.push(e.target.name)
  } else {
    seatsSelected = seatsSelected.filter((name) => e.target.name !== name);
  }
  console.log(seatsSelected);
}
```

calculations happening on a dialog

```
const handleClickOpen = () => { //open the dialog
      setOpen(true);
      console.log(seatsSelected);
      const seatTotal = seatsSelected.length
      console.log(seatTotal)
      setSeatCount(seatTotal)
      console.log(seatCount)
    };


  
    const handleClose = () => {  //close the dialog
      setOpen(false); 
    };

    

    const handleIncrement = () =>{  //increse the count
      if(counter < seatsSelected.length){
        setCounter(counter + 1)
      } else {
        setCounter(counter)
      }
      
    }

    const handleDecrement = () =>{  //decrese the count
      if(counter >= seatsSelected.length){
        setCounter(counter - 1)
      } else {
        setCounter(counter)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, like in your example, the `console.log` function runs before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(seatCount);
}, [seatCount);
```

The callback will run every time the state value changes and only after it has finished changing and a render has occurred.